# Android Studio migration to Gradle , Causing API incompatibility in gcm registration

Tags: android, gradle, google-cloud-messaging, build.gradle

Using Android Studio

I had a working notifications running app on v4.1.2 API(16) only ,Then i migrated the project to use Gradle for easier dependencies handing.

Google play service check is running good & returning SUCCESS_CODE , but when getting the reg_id it throws exception with service_not_available which .

I think it is bug from google when running on emulator(GoogleAPI) running API 18, but am debugging the app on v4.1.2 API(16) - gradle  Shows SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

This is the build.gradle

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'android'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 18
        buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 8
            targetSdkVersion 18
        }
        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'

                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']

                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }

        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+')
        compile('com.android.support:support-v13:13.0.0')
        compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.25')
    }
```

**I need to know what is wrong about this build and why all devices and emulators has that ERORR : service not available ?**